# Insert SQL com 3 arrays na mesma tabela - PYTHON

Tags: python

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de `INSERT` para o banco de dados **POSTGRES:**

```
for first in nomes:
        for second in quantidades:
                for third in produtos:
                        cursor.execute(first,second,third,str(timestampInitial))
```

**PROBLEMA**

Ela está entrando em um looping infinito, que percorre diversas vezes o mesmo valor do primeiro laço

Eu gostaria de inserir as listas `nomes, quantidades e produtos` e um único *INSERT* na mesma tabela do banco de dados, qual a forma correta de executar essa operação em python ?

Comment: Como são essas listas?

Comment: Exemplo: nomes = [u'CARLOS',u'LUIS',u'JUNIOR']

Comment: Exemplo: quantidades = ['1','2','3']

Comment: Preciso entender melhor o que você precisa, você quer inserir todos os valores de uma lista para todos os valores das outras listas ? exemplo : 0 0 0 / 0 0 1 / 0 0 2 / 0 1 0 ou você precisa que cada index das suas listas sejam inseridos com o seu index equivalente de outra lista ? exemplo : 0 0 0 / 1 1 1 / 2 2 2 ?

Comment: Preciso que seja assim: 0 0 0 / 1 1 1 / 2 2 2 o método zip(), resolveu o problema, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é um *loop* infinito, mas realmente inserirá repetido porque para cada nome da lista você percorre todas as quantidades e para cada quantidade você percorre todos os produtos. Basicamente você estará inserindo todas as combinações possíveis entre os valores e não é isso que você deseja.

Se entendi bem, você deseja inserir o primeiro item em `nomes`, com o primeiro item em `quantidades` e com o primeiro item em `produtos`, assim sucessivamente. Para tal, existe a função `zip` do Python:

```
registros = zip(nomes, quantidades, produtos)
```

E você não precisará fazer um laço de repetição para inserir um a um. Existe a função chamada `executemany` que executará uma mesma SQL múltiplas vezes conforme os dados que você informar.

Ficaria basicamente:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO ... VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
cursor.executemany(sql, registros)
```

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado, era mais simples do que parecia!